# How would I get the equivalent C# code that will recreate my runtime object in its current state?

Tags: c#, serialization

Are there any .Net libraries which can take an object and serialize it to a Stream, as the C# code that would create the object?

```
Stream fs = ...;

CSharpFormatter formatter = new CSharpFormatter();

var p = new Person { Name = "Russ", Address = "1024 Oak St" };

formatter.Serialize(fs, p);
```

At the end of this, fs would end up with a string like this written to it:

```
new Person { Name = "Russ", Address = "1024 Oak St" };
```

I think something like this would be very useful in writing unit tests from tricky runtime cases.

Comment: I picture doing a code-generation thing.  Imagine that when I discover an exceptional case, I could immediately serialize the participating objects to a string...  And then paste that string into a new unit test.  Yes, I could use BinaryFormatter or XML or JSON.  But I'm a big fan of writing C# code when I can.

Comment: Do you mean to serialize unserializable objects?

Comment: I don't really have any problem with needing a DataContract or Serializable tag.  I just want the output to be C# code that I could drop in to a unit test, for instance.

Comment: Use some reflection, that shouldn't be too difficult to implement. But things like `new Person { Name = "Russ", Address = "1024 Oak St" };` requires all Fields or Props to be public, turning an arbituary obj into this form couldn't be called lossless serialization. What about a class with no public props? For those well-encapsulated classes, this kinda quasi-serialization is pointless.

Comment: This sounds like an exceedingly _bad_ idea. At some point in the future you're going to want to deserialize this using a full C# parser, and it's going to allow users to do dangerously unintended things via those object streams.

Comment: @Need4Steed, my example was just an example.  I agree that being able to handle arbitrary .Net objects would be nice, especially if we can maintain some readability.  I'm sure Mocking frameworks have to deal with these same problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially hack a JSON serializer to do this.  Given your Person object, a JSON Serializer might return something like:

```
{"name":"Russ","Address":"1024 Oak St"}
```

From there, it's fairly straightforward to use `Split()` and `Replace()` to  get close to what you want:

```
{ Name = "Russ", Address = "1024 Oak St" }
```

The rest is just window dressing.

Comment: JSON isn't going to be able to handle cycles in my object structure, like a BinaryFormatter would.  It would be nice to have this CSharpSerializer be able to handle complex scenarios.

Comment: I have two static utility methods I use in my unit tests, `ToXml` and `FromXml<T>`.  When I want to recreate a particular object, I do a `ToXml` to `Debug.Print`, and copy/paste the resulting XML into a `FromXml<T>` call.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer but you can use classes in the [System.CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) namespace to create the code, such as [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245.aspx), then use GenerateCodeFromXXX methods in the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class to emit C#.

Another way is using the [T4 Text Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), such as [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820614.aspx). and reflection but it requires Visual Studio.